# My C# Timer code does not work

Tags: c#, timer

I coded a simple timer to run every 15 seconds, to broadcast some message. However, nothing happens.

```
  public void InitTimer()
        {
            loginTimer = new Timer();
            loginTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(loginTimer_Tick);
            loginTimer.Interval = 15000;
            loginTimer.Start();
        }

        private void loginTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Test!");
        }
```

This is my code.

I call the following when the button is clicked:

```
InitTimer();
```

But nothing happens every 15 seconds.. why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: "Nothing happens every 15 seconds" is possibly one of the most amusing phrases I've seen in a question ...

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in both `InitTimer()` and `loginTimer_Tick`? Also, are you building in Debug mode?

Comment: Is the parent thread ending?

Comment: Did you really register a listener for the `Debug.WriteLine` or you expect it to show in the Console like `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 4):

I did everything you said and didn't have any problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer loginTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitTimer()
    {
        loginTimer = new Timer();
        loginTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(loginTimer_Tick);
        loginTimer.Interval = 1000;
        loginTimer.Start();
    }

    private void loginTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test!");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitTimer();
    }
}
```

[image]
Show us your code or find an error anywhere else.

Comment: This doesn't answers question, but +1 for efforts you made

Answer (score 3):

The code works fine. `But nothing happens every 15 seconds.. why is that?` Well, stuff happens, but you can't see it. Why? Because you are using [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7821bed5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Unlike [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), Debug outputs to a [`TraceListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), not the Console. In order to see the output, you need to register a listener (which I'm sure you didn't).

So to verify if your code is really working, register a listener, use an other way (like Console.WriteLine or MessageBox.Show) or just *set a breakpoint in your `loginTimer_Tick method`*.

To register a listener and output to the Console, you can proceed like this :

```
TextWriterTraceListener listener = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(listener);
```

Just be sure you are in Debug mode (or that you defined manually the `debug` flag).

As a side note, your delegate constructor call is redundant, you can shorten it to

```
loginTimer.Tick += loginTimer_Tick;
```